# An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters

Tags: python, unit-testing, appium

Appium automation runs and ends correctly inside one class, but fails when another class is created.

I tried to to delete all attributes in **init**, except first one and it helps.

Main Class(works well)

```
import unittest
from appium import webdriver
from ScreenObjects.SendMessage import SendMsg


class AppTestAppium(unittest.TestCase):

  def setUp(self):
      desired_caps = {}
      desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
      desired_caps['platformVersion'] = ''
      desired_caps['deviceName'] = '81e9b20e'
      desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'org.telegram.messenger'
      desired_caps['appActivity'] = 'org.telegram.ui.LaunchActivity'
      desired_caps['noReset'] = 'True'
      self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub',desired_caps)

  def tearDown(self):
      "Tear down the test"

      self.driver.quit()


  def test_send_messge_to_olga(self):
      "Test is sending message"


      contactItem = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.view.ViewGroup[contains(@index,'2')]")
      contactItem.click()
      elementTypeField = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.EditText[contains(@index,'1')]")
      elementTypeField.clear()
      elementTypeField.send_keys("Hello. If you are reading this, my first appium automation has passed")
      sendButton = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.ImageView[@content-desc ='Send']")
      sendButton.click()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Main class(fails)

```
import unittest
from appium import webdriver
from ScreenObjects.SendMessage import SendMsg


class AppTestAppium(unittest.TestCase):

  def setUp(self):
      desired_caps = {}
      desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
      desired_caps['platformVersion'] = ''
      desired_caps['deviceName'] = '81e9b20e'
      desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'org.telegram.messenger'
      desired_caps['appActivity'] = 'org.telegram.ui.LaunchActivity'
      desired_caps['noReset'] = 'True'
      self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub',desired_caps)

  def tearDown(self):
      "Tear down the test"

      self.driver.quit()


  def test_send_messge_to_olga(self):
      "Test is sending message"

      send_message = SendMsg(self.driver)
      send_message.chooseContact()
      send_message.typeMsg()
      send_message.clickSend()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

with one more Class (fails)

```
class SendMsg(object):

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.contactItem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.view.ViewGroup[contains(@index,'2')]")
        self.elementTypeField = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.EditText[contains(@index,'1')]")
        self.sendButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.ImageView[@content-desc ='Send']")


    def chooseContact(self):
        self.contactItem.click()

    def typeMsg(self):
        self.elementTypeField.clear()
        self.elementTypeField.send_keys("Hello")

    def clickSend(self):
        self.sendButton.click()
```

I expect TEST PASSED, but the actual output is 'An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.'

Comment: What element is failing to be located? The most obvious answer if one of your xpath is not pointing to the right element but it is impossible to tell without a trackback.

Comment: self.elementTypeField = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//android.widget.EditText[contains(@index,'1')]")

Comment: Can you post the entire trackback?

Comment: The driver does not actually query the gui itself, but rather the driver's `PageSource` xml value of the current window handle. So first of, make sure you have the correct window handle. Second, verify if you see the element your looking for in the xml. Third, try debugging your XPath expression. A easy way to debug a XPath expression is to copy over the xml to a online XPath expression tool and apply your XPath there. Adjust your expression until you get the expected result.